# What part of my code has gone wrong? can you tell me please?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[here is guide output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0UUa.jpg)

here is my code I'm working on. I don't know how to make the load button work and compute button also, It should display the output but nothing happen when I click it. Also there's no error so I can't figure out what's wrong. The function part is very hard and I don't know how to place it correctly.

```
function dispInfo() {
    var code = document.getElementById('code').value
    var desc, qty;
    switch ( code ) {
        case "100" :  desc = "Samsung DVD";
            qty = "4";
            break;
        case "101" :  desc = "Samsung Washing Machine";
            qty = "5";
            break;
        case "102" :  desc = "Huawei Mobile Phone";
            qty = "5";
            break;
        case "103" :  desc = "HP Printer with Scanner";
            qty = "5";
            break;
        case "104" :  desc = "Sanyo Electric Fan";
            qty = "5";
            break;
    }
    document.getElementById('desc').value = desc
    document.getElementById('qty').value = qty
}
function calc() {
    var newQty = document.getElementById('newQty').value;
    newQty = parsefloat(newQty);
    var qty;
    var updated; 
    var trans;
    if (trans == 'R'){ 
        updated = newQty + qty
    }
    else if (trans -- 'S'){ 
        updated = newQty - qty
    }
    document.getElementById('trans').value = trans
    document.getElementById('updated').value = updated
}
function load() {
    let code = document.getElementById("code").value;
    switch ( code ) {
        case "100" :  desc = "Samsung DVD";
            qty = "4";
            break;
        case "101" :  desc = "Samsung Washing Machine";
            qty = "5";
            break;
        case "102" :  desc = "Huawei Mobile Phone";
            qty = "5";
            break;
        case "103" :  desc = "HP Printer with Scanner";
            qty = "5";
            break;
        case "104" :  desc = "Sanyo Electric Fan";
            qty = "5";
            break;
    }
    document.getElementById('desc').value = desc
    document.getElementById('qty').value = qty
}
```

Comment: can you share your html too?

Comment: `else if (trans -- 'S'){` should probably be `else if (trans == 'S'){`

Comment: Please post some of your HTML code as well. Before you edited your post the script start tag sayed: '<script language="Javascript">'. It is deprecated, use: '<script type="text/javascript">'

Comment: when are ur buttons being called? can u share the HTML? also your else block should have else if (trans === 'S') {}

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code, you appear to be a complete beginner so here go some corrections.

```js
function dispInfo() {
        var code = document.getElementById('code').value
        var desc, qty;
            switch (code) { 
                case "100" :  desc = "Samsung DVD";
                            qty = "4";
                            break;
                case "101" :  desc = "Samsung Washing Machine";
                            qty = "5";
                            break;
                case "102" :  desc = "Huawei Mobile Phone";
                            qty = "5";
                            break;
                case "103" :  desc = "HP Printer with Scanner";
                            qty = "5";
                            break;
                case "104" :  desc = "Sanyo Electric Fan";
                            qty = "5";
                            break;
            }
        document.getElementById('desc').value = desc; //missing semicolon
        document.getElementById('qty').value = qty; //missing semicolon
    }
    function calc() {
        var newQty = document.getElementById('newQty').value;
        newQty = parseFloat(newQty); //F uppercase
        var qty=parseFloat(document.getElementById('qty').value); //read value
        var updated; 
        var trans=document.getElementById('trans').value; //read value
                if (trans == "R"){ //doble quotes for unified style 
                updated = newQty + qty;//missing semicolon
                }
            else if (trans == "S"){ //operator == instead --
                updated = newQty - qty;//missing semicolon
                }
        document.getElementById('trans').value = trans; //missing semicolon
        document.getElementById('updated').value = updated; //missing semicolon
    }
    /*<! –– For Load Button––>*/    
    function load() {
        let code = document.getElementById("code").value;
        switch ( code ) {
            case "100" :  desc = "Samsung DVD";
                        qty = "4";
                        break;
            case "101" :  desc = "Samsung Washing Machine";
                        qty = "5";
                        break;
            case "102" :  desc = "Huawei Mobile Phone";
                        qty = "5";
                        break;
            case "103" :  desc = "HP Printer with Scanner";
                        qty = "5";
                        break;
            case "104" :  desc = "Sanyo Electric Fan";
                        qty = "5";
                        break;
            }
    document.getElementById('desc').value = desc;//missing semicolon
    document.getElementById('qty').value = qty;//missing semicolon
    }
```